# Insert text command into Emacs that groups with undo

Tags: emacs, insert, elisp

I'm trying to bind a key to insert a character into the current buffer.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<some-key>")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (insert-char ?\c)))
```

That works fine, but when I call it multiple times then call `undo` only the last character is undone.

How do make Emacs undo all consecutive inserts--the way Emacs does it with `self-insert-command`?

Comment: See the Elisp manual, node [`Undo`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Undo.html).

Answer (score 1):

`undo` works on `buffer-undo-list` and normally it processes entries in the list up to the first `nil` element (ignoring the very first entry if it is `nil`).  See the docstring for it for more info.

If you look at the value of `buffer-undo-list` after each call to `insert-char` you'll see that another `nil` and cons have been prepended to it.

So, if you want your function to group inserts into one set of consecutive entries in the `buffer-undo-list` then you will have to have it remove the `nil` at the beginning of the list before it calls `insert-char`, but perhaps only if that `nil` was added during the last invocation of your function.  (`self-insert-command`, and its moral equivalents, internally keep track of the last `nil` in the list with an internal global variable)

I'll leave the latter part of only coalescing inserts from your own function to you (hint:  use `setq` to save a pointer to the current undo list after the insert into a global variable, and `eq` to compare that global with the undo list before the insert).

Your sample modified to *always* coalesce its inserts with any previous entry in the undo list (and corrected to use `insert-char` correctly):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "c")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (if (eq nil (car buffer-undo-list))
        (setq buffer-undo-list (cdr buffer-undo-list)))
    (insert-char ?\c 1)))
```